# Date picker in iOS

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I pick the date from date picker but it shows only time at the time of run.

I want only date, not time, but it show only time not date. I already set date format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
NSString *formatedDate=[[NSString alloc]init];
formatedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.DatePicker.date];
self.SelectedDate.text =formatedDate;

[DatePicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
_goDateForcustmoeDetail=formatedDate;
isTouchedFirst=NO;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

to

```
DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

Only four modes are available:

> - UIDatePickerModeTime,
> - UIDatePickerModeDate,
> - UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
> - UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer

Comment: Great, can you please accept my answer and UpVote it.

Answer (score 1):

**Set datePicker Mode to `UIDatePickerModeDate` .. Simple !!**

```
DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

@**only four modes are available:**

> UIDatePickerModeTime,
>
> UIDatePickerModeDate,
>
> UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
>
> UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop UIDatePicker in your view controller.
Add this code you will get only date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
_DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
NSString *formatedDate=[[NSString alloc]init];
formatedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.DatePicker.date];

[_DatePicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
```